# Copy data from multiple selections

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel worksheet (Job card) which calculates normal hours and overtime hours for weekdays and then hours @ 1.5 and double the rate for saturdays and sundays. This information is as per picture below:

[image: Jobcard]

On worksheet (Jobcard) rows 10 through 33 column A, E, F and G contains the information I need to copy to an invoice. However if Row 10 has both column E and F completed then on the invoice it needs to be split into rows on sheet Inv & Stmnt as per picture:

[image: Inv & Stmnt]

...at the same time of copying this data I need to be able to determine which column the information copied from and then copy the appropriate rate which is on a 3rd sheet called static data in Cell B2 for normal rate, B3 for 1.5 rate and B4 for 2.0 rate.

Thus basically what I'm looking to do is:

If I worked on a monday starting at 08:00 in the morning and finshed at 20:00 at night. the invoice needs to state that on the monday whatever the date was 8 hours will be charged at the normal rate and copy the rate from "static data B2 and 4 hours at the 1.5 rate and copy the data from "static data B3" and if I worked on a sunday it needs to copy the data from "static data B4" into the rate column on the invoice sheet

If anybody can help with this I would really appreciate.

Comment: Sorry forgot to ask if there is a formula or VBA that I can use to do this?